# Is Multiplying a decimal number where all results are full integers, considered Floating Point Math?

Tags: c, floating-point, fixed-point

Sorry for the wordy title. My code is targeting a microcontroller (msp430) with no floating point unit, but this should apply to any similar MCU.

If I am multiplying a large runtime variable with what would normally be considered a floating point decimal number (1.8), is this still treated like floating point math by the MCU or compiler?

My simplified code is:

```
int multip = 0xf;          // Can be from 0-15, not available at compile time
int holder = multip * 625; // 0 - 9375
holder = holder * 1.8;     // 0 - 16875`
```

Since the result will always be a positive full, real integer number, is it still floating point math as far as the MCU or compiler are concerned, or is it fixed point?

(I realize I could just multiply by 18, but that would require declaring a 32bit long instead of a 16 bit int then dividing and downcasting for the array it will be put in, trying to skimp on memory here)

Comment: When you say "floating point," do you mean the [IEEE-754 variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)?

Comment: According to my experience, most compiler treat 1.8 as a floating number even though there is no floating point unit on your chip. But operations with floating point numbers cost much more than those with integers. So it depend on your requirements.

Comment: Why would positivity matter?

Comment: @user2357112 fixed. Meant full integers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would assume so

Comment: why don't use `holder = holder*9/5;`? It's faster on computers without FPU, and more correct when you need truncation

Comment: Downvote on a 3 year old question, hmmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not an integer; it rounds to an integer.

```
9375 * 1.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

yields

```
16875.0000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875
```

which rounds (in double precision floating point) to 16875.

Comment: That's because the compiler or mcu inherently treats 1.8 as a float, immediately creating imprecision right? Shame. Thanks.

Comment: You could always do the calculation as `holder *= 2; holder -= holder/10;`

Comment: @cde Not the MCU, but the compiler treats 1.8 as a float. The MCU is stupid that it just executes the instructions in the hex file(output of the linker). So it's the compiler that optimizes the floating point operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a floating-point multiply, I know of no compiler that will determine that there's a way to do that in fixed-point instead.  (That does not mean they do not exist, but it ... seems unlikely.)

I assume you simplified away something important, because it seems like you could just do:

```
result = multip * 1125;
```

and get the final result directly.

I'd go for [chux's formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18861893/1256452) if there's some reason you can't just multiply by 1125.

Answer (score 0):

Confident FP code will be created for

```
holder = holder * 1.8
```

To avoid FP and 32-bit math, given the OP values of

```
int multip = 0xf;    // Max 15
unsigned holder = multip * 625; // Max 9375
// holder = holder * 1.8; 
// alpha depends on rounding desired,  e.g. 2 for round to nearest.
holder += (holder*4u + alpha)/5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `int x` is non-negative, you can compute `x *= 1.8` rounded to nearest using only `int` arithmetic, without overflow unless the final result overflows, with:

```
x - (x+2)/5 + x
```

For truncation instead of round-to-nearest, use:

```
x - (x+4)/5 + x
```

If `x` may be negative, some additional work is needed.